# Ionic Form Validator with Toast

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I absolutly need your help :p

I'm new with Ionic but i really want to learn so excuse if i'm not doing well !

Here's my code HTML : `

See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
-->

## Inscrivez-vous

```
<form [formGroup]="formgroup">
<ion-list class="item">

    <ion-row radio-group>

        <ion-col>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Homme</ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="homme"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-item>
           <ion-label>Femme</ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="femme"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Prénom</ion-label>
    <ion-input class="colorInput" type="text" formControlName="prenom" ></ion-input>
  </ion-item>



  <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Date de Naissance</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime class="colorInput" displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" ></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>


  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Mail</ion-label>
    <ion-input class="colorInput" type="text" formControlName="mail"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Mot de passe</ion-label>
    <ion-input class="colorInput" placeholder="Min. 6 caractères" type="password" formControlName="motDePasse"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

```
<button ion-button round class="button" (click)="ToastError();">Connexion</button>
```

`

And my TS File here :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-sign-in',
  templateUrl: 'sign-in.html',
})
export class SignInPage {

  formgroup: FormGroup;

  prenom: AbstractControl;
  mail: AbstractControl;
  motDePasse: AbstractControl;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public formbuilder: FormBuilder, public toastCtrl: ToastController) {

    this.formgroup = formbuilder.group({

      prenom: ['',Validators.required],

      mail: ['',Validators.required],
      motDePasse: ['',Validators.required]
    });


    this.prenom = this.formgroup.controls['prenom'];

    this.mail = this.formgroup.controls['mail'];
    this.motDePasse = this.formgroup.controls['motDePasse'];
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad SignInPage');
  }

  ToastError(prenom) {
    const Toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'pas ok',
      duration: 2000
    });

    if (prenom == '1' ) {
      Toast.present();
    }

  }
}
```

The goal is to check in a first time if the user wrote his name, if it's not the case i want a toast to appear.

If you have some ideas :)

Have a good day/night !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just add this button to .html**

```
<button ion-button round class="button" (click)="ToastError(formgroup.value.prenom)">Connexion</button>
```

**And this is .ts function**

```
ToastError(prenom) {

        const Toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
            message: 'pas ok',
            duration: 2000
        });

        prenom ? console.log('prenom found') : Toast.present();

    }
```

**Feel free to comment for more help**

Comment: Thank you it works ! I want to do it for all fields, i just have to duplicate the code ?

Comment: first, upvote me and tick this answer :) and actually you need to do pass all fields like "formgroup.value" to the function through button. Then rest work on ToastError() function . If you need more help then comment me. happy coding bro..

Comment: It works ! Thank you bro, don't you have a youtube channel ?  Or Udemy ? :)

Comment: Not yet bro, but very soon I am going to start a youtube chanel.. :)

Comment: Oh really nice ! Give me your link when you will start, i will sub with no hesitation :p